# При реализации интерфейса Spring ищет файл

Tags: java, spring

Я сделал Bean UserService, нужно реализовать в нём интерфейс Listener (Paper API), но, почему-то после этого он пытается найти его как файл. Почему? Если убрать из implements Listener, то всё нормально.

Кое-что удалял там, но происходит при context.refresh();
https://pastebin.com/dTWNGgss

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
context.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
context.setConfigLocation("spring.xml");
context.refresh();
```

```
[17:44:50] [Server thread/WARN]: [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [UserService]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/bukkit/event/Listener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[17:44:50] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Lib v1 (Is it up to date?)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [UserService]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/bukkit/event/Listener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:435) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:470) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_15_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:384) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:482) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:298) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_15_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:885) ~[patched_1.15.2.jar:git-Paper-99]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/bukkit/event/Listener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:56) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:686) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1007) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:378) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[?:?]
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по приложенной ошибке у вас в classpath приложения не загрузился класс - проверьте есть ли необходимая зависимость и не перетирается ли она другой библиотекой.

Также иногда помогает очистить локальный .m2 с пакетом зависимости и после этого повторно собрать проект.

Comment: проверил, всё нормально, а эта ошибка всё равно появляется...
почему он ищет интерфейс как ресурс?

Comment: classpath описывает, где компилятор и интерпретатор ищут пакет файлов . class для загрузки. С точки зрения компилятора все классы программы - ресурсы. В ошибке написано в classpath не найден класс Failed to parse configuration class [UserService]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/bukkit/event/Listener.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist, соответственно в загрузчик классов он не попал. Мой совет вам - уйдите от конфигурирования бинов в xml к конфигурации в java-файлах с помощью аннотаций.

Comment: Конфигурировать в xml сложнее чем на аннотацияъх и нужен солидный опыт и хорошее знание того как работает конфигурирование таким образом.

Comment: Возможно еще, что у вас в spring.xml не прописано определение бина org/bukkit/event/Listener.class, поэтому он не попадает в classpath

Comment: это не бин, это класс из библиотеки. кстати сказать, я попробовал более старую версию библиотеки и всё заработало, поставил новую и снова ошибка. не совсем понимаю, почему там ошибка с classpath и как конкретно с ним работает spring, ведь с более старой версией всё хорошо
библиотека Paper API